# use different kubectl configs in different terminal sessions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

If I run `kubectl get svc`, it seems to be the same across terminal sessions - how can use a local configuration that's only loaded for my current terminal session?

If the answer is a local config file and using KUBECONFIG env var to point to it, then how can I generate a local config file? If I use:

```
export KUBECONFIG=`dirname "$BASH_SOURCE"/conf`
aws eks update-kubeconfig --profile=alex --name ignitecluster
```

I get this error:

> Content not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable with a value that includes the relevant Kubernetes configuration file, the environment variable only applies to your current session/window.

Comment: nice but about the same config file in `.kube/config` but a different configuration in that file?

Comment: I updated the OP with more details, ty